# In which way to prove that the set has the measure zero in R3?

Tags: real-numbers, rational-numbers

I can understand this task in the way that we should prove that there are less numbers in the rational set compared to the numbers in the real set ?

TO PROVE:

The set A is described as follows:

$A=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : 0 \leq x \leq 1,0\leq y \leq 1, 0\leq z\leq 1,x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

I've looked the theory for "measure" and the number of real ($\mathbb{R}$) and rational ($\mathbb{Q}$) numbers. And then?

Comment: Your definition of $A$ is unclear. Do you mean all triples of reals (inside the "unit box") with first coordinate rational?

Comment: No. Between 0 and 1, the triple is in Q. So is the question i need to tackle.

Comment: By saying "the triple is in Q" in your last comment, do you mean all three of x,y,z are in Q?

Comment: @coffeemath: It doesn't really matter whether all $x,y,z$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$, or only $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, they are both zero sets.

Andrej: Please make use of MathJax when typesetting mathematical formulas. I've tried to fix the LaTeX in your original question, however, I was not sure whether you meant that $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Q}$ or only $x\in\mathbb{Q}$. Use the "edit" button to modify your question. Furthermore: it would actually be nice to have a clearly formulated question. "Let $A = \{...\}$" is not an interesting theorem. "And then?" is not a proper mathematical question.

Comment: Do you know how to prove the rational numbers have measure zero in ${\mathbb R}?$ A very similar approach will work here, except instead of covering each rational number with an interval having an appropriately small length, cover your set with really thin sheet-like looking solids (i.e. nearly planar by virtue of being so thin) that are perpendicular to the $x$-axis and parallel to the $yz$-plane.

Comment: The fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable is really helpful for showing that $A$ is a zero set, however, being countable is not a necessary condition for being a measure-zero set. Think of the Cantor set for example: it has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, but it's still a measure-zero set.